# Nginx Failing to Start

Tags: arch-linux, nginx

I run Arch Linux and when I run:

`sudo systemctl start nginx.service`

I get the following message in the journal:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-15 11:17:03 BST; 45s ago
  Process: 1542 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 15 11:17:03 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 15 11:17:03 nginx[1542]: 2019/05/15 11:17:03 [emerg] 1542#1542: a duplicate listen 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:42
May 15 11:17:03  systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 15 11:17:03  systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 11:17:03  systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I don't understand the error here. How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-15 11:36:36 BST; 9s ago
  Process: 1667 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 15 11:36:36  systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 15 11:36:36  nginx[1667]: 2019/05/15 11:36:36 [emerg] 1667#1667: getpwnam("www-data") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:3
May 15 11:36:36  systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 15 11:36:36  systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 11:36:36  systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: that grep doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something else which listen on port 80, check line:

```
duplicate listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

To see which PID listen you can try

```
netstat -anp|grep :80
```

If something is wrong with nginx config you can try this minimal one:

```
daemon            on;
worker_processes  2;
user              www-data;
events {
    use           epoll;
    worker_connections  128;
}
error_log         logs/error.log info;
http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       mime.types;
    charset       utf-8;
    access_log    logs/access.log  combined;
    server {
        server_name   localhost;
        listen        *:80;
        error_page    500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location      / {
            root      html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did fuser 80/tcp but it returns nothing

Comment: The netstat returns tcp        1      0 192.168.161.43:39038    216.58.198.238:80       CLOSE_WAIT  1766/chromium --typ

Comment: I ran the fuser as root but still nothing

Comment: I even rebooted my machine

Comment: @C.S, so you have something wrong in to the nginx config

Comment: How can I generate a fresh config?

Comment: @C.S, i edit my answer with one minimal config

Comment: I get a new error now

Comment: I posted it above

Comment: @C.S, set the user `www-data` to some user you have on your machine. Or create this new user

Comment: That's crazy. I added my username and it still complains with the same message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93667/discussion-between-c-s-and-romeo-ninov).

Comment: Something badly went wrong with the installation I think - some stuff was missing Working now